# How to proof $\cos(z+\omega) = \cos(z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I have to proof that if for any $z$:
 $$\cos(z+\omega) = \cos(z)$$

then $\omega = 2\pi k \quad (k = 0, \pm 1, \pm 2 \ldots)$

I have no idea how to prrof it strictly

Comment: $\cos z\cos w-\sin z\sin w=\cos z$ and $\sin2k\pi=0$.

Comment: This question can't be answered without a proper definition of the cosine and the properties that can be used. (Because by default it is well-known that the period of the trigonometric functions is $2\pi$).

Comment: Is $z$ real of complex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$cos(a+b)=cos(a)cos(b)-sin(a)sin(b)$ if $b=2\pi k$, $cos(b)=1$ and $sin(b)=0$.

Comment: If the periodicity of the sine/cosine cannot be taken for granted, why could we use the addition formula or even the particular values as $2k\pi$ ?

Answer (score 0):

$$ \cos{(z+\omega)}-\cos{z} = -2\sin{(z+\omega/2)}\sin{(\omega/2)}, $$
and hence we require $\sin{(\omega/2)}=0$, i.e. $\omega/2=\pi k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.